# Can Google Apps Script blobs be returned with their content type set to Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As part of a suite of tools I am developing for the company I work for, I have an add-on in development that when first installed generates all the relevant files and folders for the suite.

Due to the complexity of some of the files I discovered that using the following code was the quickest way to generate the files:

```
function createTemplate(branchId){
var home=DriveApp.getFolderById(branchId)
var master=DriveApp.getFileById(stringId).getBlob();
home.createFile(master);
}
```

I am presented with the problem, however, that all the files generate as PDFs. I am aware that this is because the default blob content type is the PDF file type and that `getAs(contentType)` can be used to specify the desired blob content type; but I have struggled to find any documentation specifying how to call the content type as a Spreadsheet, for example.

Is this possible and I've just missed somewhere in Google's documentation how to specify content type as spreadsheet or is it no possible and can blobs only be returned with content types of PDF or image types?

UPDATE: So I discovered accidentally that the content type for spreadsheets would appear to have be specified by `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` However, I now get the error `Converting from application/pdf to application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet is not supported.`

FURTHER UPDATE: Potential solution using different route found using the below script:

```
function createTemplate(branchId){
var home=DriveApp.getFolderById(branchId);
var master=DriveApp.getFileById("fileId").makeCopy("PP Template", home);
}
```

Although this had around an 8 second run-time so not the quickest thing in the world. Blob related answer still welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, blob will not do what you want to at this time. There is a reason that DocumentApp.create, etc. exist. They are the function calls that Google wants you to make for what you want to do. They don't want 13 ways to perform the same function.